# i want to update password of user in predix uaa but showing me error?

Tags: rest, cloudfoundry-uaa, predix

https://77b186f0-b9a1-4956-b72a-630108a331b7.predix-uaa.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/Users/daa7daaa-23b3-409d-b6ce-0857b76a62de/s102

Accept:application/json
scope:password.write
aud:password

curl command
curl --request POST \
  --url https://77b186f0-b9a1-4956-b72a-630108a331b7.predix-uaa.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/Users/daa7daaa-23b3-409d-b6ce-0857b76a62de/dff \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'aud: password' \
  --header 'authorization: bearer {token}' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --header 'pragma: no-cache' \
  --header 'scope: password.write'

UserId with password

for reference
https://github.com/GESoftware-CF/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Learn [ask] and [mcve]. It's only a 5 minute read and will save you hours. We want to help, but we need some context. You can use the code formatting options in the toolbar. You can edit your question. In fact, here's a link!: [edit] We have no idea what kind of API or context this is. Please edit your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The URL seems incorrect to me. It should end in .../password. The doc you cite has a curl example...

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/Users/a9717027-b838-40bd-baca-b9f9d38a440d/password' -i -X PUT -H 'Authorization: Bearer tURh3jpUFIvZ96G9o' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"oldPassword":"secr3T","password":"n3wAw3som3Passwd"}'
```

See https://github.com/GESoftware-CF/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#change-password-put-users-id-password